# spring websocket scope missing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websocket

when i use the new "websocket" scope in a component, i get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope name 'websocket'
```

controller:

```
@RestController
@Scope(value = "websocket", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
@Slf4j
public class GenericWrapperController extends TextWebSocketHandler {
```

spring version 4.3.3.RELEASE and 1.4.1.RELEASE for springboot. my guess its version related however the docs say this scope was introduced in 4.1 already.

Comment: just tested with up to date versions (4.3.5.RELEASE and boot 1.4.3.RELEASE) no change

Answer (score 0):

annotation 
`@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker`
is required in a configuration class to enable the websocket scope. `@EnableWebSocket` is NOT suffcicient

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the error :(

When i add @EnableWebSocketMessageBroker i get another error

```
11:11:35.789 [main] [] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - SpringApplication.java:821 - Application run failed org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'subProtocolWebSocketHandler'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No handlers
```

ps: I'm not using STOPM and no StompEndpointRegistry