# Springboot not creating new instance of bean with scope "prototype" in new websocket sessions

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, websocket

I'm using springboot websocket api (not STOMP), my goal ist to create one instance of the handler for every websocket Client session.

So my Goal is to get at least new instance for every thread. Is that even possible?

I'v configured the websocket via registry.addHandler while implementing the interface WebSocketConfigurer,

This is how looks the WebSocketConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
class WebSocketConfig(
    val webSocketHandler: WebSocketHandler
) : WebSocketConfigurer {

    override fun registerWebSocketHandlers(registry: WebSocketHandlerRegistry) {
        registry.addHandler(webSocketHandler, "/messages")
    }

}
```

I'v annotate the WebSocketHandler with "@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)" with the hope that i will get a new instance of the handler by every new websocket session.

This is how looks the WebSocketHandler:

```
@Component
@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
class WebSocketHandler : TextWebSocketHandler() {

    private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.javaClass)

    public override fun handleTextMessage(session: WebSocketSession, message: TextMessage) {
        log.info("handleTextMessage  with Message {}", message.payload)
    }

    override fun afterConnectionClosed(session: WebSocketSession, status: CloseStatus) {
        log.info("afterConnectionClosed, sessionId: {} ", session.id)
    }

    override fun afterConnectionEstablished(session: WebSocketSession) {
        log.info("afterConnectionEstablished. hashcode: {}", this.javaClass.hashCode())
    }
}
```

I expect that springboot will create a new instance every time when a client session is starten.

Unfortunately the same handler processes all the client-websocket-sessions in differents threads :(

This is what my logging shows:

```
10:47:04.030 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] [] INFO  d.a.t.s.e.c.ClientWebSocketHandler - ClientWebSocketHandler.kt:43 - afterConnectionEstablished. hashcode: 1784908921
...
10:47:07.156 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [] INFO  d.a.t.s.e.c.ClientWebSocketHandler - ClientWebSocketHandler.kt:43 - afterConnectionEstablished. hashcode: 1784908921
```

I'v tried to use the annotation @Scope(scopeName = "websocket", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS), but i get the following error everytime when client websocket session is startet:
`No Scope registered for scope name 'websocket'`

Comment: maybe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41403693/spring-websocket-scope-missing) you will find the reason why you have got `No Scope registered for scope name 'websocket'`

Comment: Thank you Lisa for the answer but it don't help me :(
When i add the @EnableWebSocketMessageBroker i get the error "Failed to start bean 'subProtocolWebSocketHandler'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No handlers"
ps: im not using StompEndpointRegistry

Comment: maybe if you will try to use `@SessionScope` on `WebSocketHandler` it will create new bean for every session and it can meet your requirements.

Comment: with @SessionScope im getting another error "11:28:46.416 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] [] ERROR o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - DirectJDKLog.java:175 - Error reading request, ignored
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ScopeNotActiveException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.WebSocketHandler': Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread;"